# Polymer Data Bindings: Curly vs Square brackets

Tags: data-binding, polymer, web-component, polymer-3.x

Reading through the `Polymer 3.0` documentation, I noticed that both curly `{{}}` and square `[[]]` brackets are used. If any, what is the difference between these two methods of data-binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-binding) states:

> Whether data flow goes down from host to target, up from target to
>   host, or both ways is controlled by the type of binding annotation and
>   the configuration of the target property.
>
> - Double-curly brackets ({{ }}) support both upward and downward data flow.
> - Double square brackets ([[ ]]) are one-way, and support only downward data flow.